# Xcode 7 IOS 9 Google AdMob Tracking

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, xcode7

I wrote my app in Xcode 6 with IOS 8 and Google AdMob, which was working correctly. Now in Xcode 7 I'm getting the message from Google in Log that              `Advertising tracking may be disabled. To get test ads on this device, enable advertising tracking.` Maybe it's because of -canOpenURL error?(`-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "kindle://home" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme kindle"`)

Answer (score 18):

This message will come up if you have limited ad tracking in your settings. On your device, check that **Limit Ad Tracking** is not enabled:

- Settings -> Privacy -> Advertising

Comment: Thank you for this. Helped me fix the problem on my end.

Comment: This option is greyed out. I am unable to change the settings :/

Comment: Any Ad not showing issues should redirect here! Legend!

Comment: If the option is greyed out, this is usually due to your current Apple account (age, security settings..). Just logoff (temporary) and you can change the setting.